# installing tomcat and java on centos using bash

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat

i am having a problem starting the tomcat service properly after installing it. i am using centos 7 bash 4.

if the **tomcat user** and the **tomcat service name** are the same my script works fine, and gets the service pid at the end, but if they are different then something goes wrong and the service does not work properly and it does not get service pid.

here are the scripts that i am using.

can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this conflict?

thanks .

**deployScript.sh**

```html
#!/bin/bash

tomcatDirName="tomcat802"
tomcatSvcName="tomcatSvc"
tomcatSvcUsr="tomcatUsr"
tomcatSvcGrp="tomcatGrp"

installationPath="/opt/app"

javaDirName="java"
javaDirPath="$installationPath/$javaDirName"
jdkDirPath="$javaDirPath/jdk1.8.0_45"

userHomePath="$installationPath/$tomcatSvcUsr"
tomcatDirPath="$installationPath/$tomcatDirName"
tomcatConfPath="$tomcatDirPath/conf"
tomcatLogsPath="$tomcatDirPath/logs"
tomcatBinPath="$tomcatDirPath/bin"
tomcatLogsTomcat="$tomcatLogsPath/tomcat"
tomcatLogsAccess="$tomcatLogsPath/access"

setEnvShPath="$tomcatBinPath/setenv.sh"

catalinaShSearch='CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE.*'
catalinaShReplace='CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/tomcat/catalina.out'
catalinaShPath="$tomcatBinPath/catalina.sh"

initDTomcatFilePath="/etc/init.d/$tomcatSvcName"

catalinaLogsSearch='${catalina.base}/logs'
catalinaLogsReplace='${catalina.base}/logs/tomcat'
loggingPropertiesPath="$tomcatConfPath/logging.properties"
serverXMLPath="$tomcatConfPath/server.xml"
maxPostSize="15728640"

##Download Tomcat
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.21/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.21.tar.gz

# Download JDK
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b14/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz"

wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm

yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install xmlstarlet
yum -y install htop

mkdir -p $tomcatDirPath
mkdir -p $javaDirPath
mkdir -p $userHomePath

tar -xzf jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz -C $javaDirPath
rm -f  $jdkDirPath/javafx-src.zip
rm -f  $jdkDirPath/src.zip

tar -xzf apache-tomcat-8.0.21.tar.gz -C $tomcatDirPath --strip-components=1

rm -rf  $tomcatDirPath/webapps/docs
rm -rf  $tomcatDirPath/webapps/examples
rm -rf  $tomcatDirPath/webapps/host-manager 
rm -rf  $tomcatDirPath/webapps/ROOT/*

# add user and permissions

groupadd $tomcatSvcGrp
useradd -M -s /sbin/nologin -g $tomcatSvcGrp -d $userHomePath $tomcatSvcUsr

findAndReplace() {
 declare -A TomcatInitD=(
  ["^CATALINA_HOME.*"]="CATALINA_HOME=$tomcatDirPath"
  #["^TOMCAT_USER.*"]="TOMCAT_USER=$tomcatSvcUsr"
  #["^TOMCAT_SVC.*"]="TOMCAT_SVC=$tomcatSvcName"
  ["^export JAVA_HOME=.*"]="export JAVA_HOME=$jdkDirPath"
 )

 for i in "${!TomcatInitD[@]}"
 do
  value="${TomcatInitD[$i]}"
  key="$i"
  sed -i -e "s~$key~$value~" $initDTomcatFilePath
 done 
}

cp tomcat801_init.d.txt $initDTomcatFilePath
cp setenv.sh $setEnvShPath

if [ -f $initDTomcatFilePath ]
 then
  findAndReplace
 else
  cp tomcat801_init.d.txt $initDTomcatFilePath
  findAndReplace 
fi 

chown $tomcatSvcUsr $initDTomcatFilePath
chgrp $tomcatSvcGrp $initDTomcatFilePath
chmod g+rwx $initDTomcatFilePath

chown $tomcatSvcUsr $tomcatDirPath
chgrp -R $tomcatSvcGrp $tomcatDirPath
chmod g+rwx $tomcatDirPath

# i have no idea why is it for and why it is not working
#chkconfig --add $tomcatSvcName
#chkconfig --level 234 $tomcatSvcName on

cd $installationPath
chown -R $tomcatSvcUsr *
chgrp -R $tomcatSvcGrp * 

chmod g+rwx $tomcatConfPath

cd $tomcatConfPath
chmod g+r *
cd $installationPath

# modify tomcat logging path in conf\logging.properties by adding tomcat folder ${catalina.base}/logs/tomcat
sed -i -e "s~$catalinaLogsSearch~$catalinaLogsReplace~" $loggingPropertiesPath

mkdir $tomcatLogsTomcat
chown -R $tomcatSvcUsr $tomcatLogsTomcat
chgrp -R $tomcatSvcGrp $tomcatLogsTomcat

# modify server.xml set acces log path to logs/access
xmlstarlet ed -L -u /Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve[@directory]/@directory -v "logs/access" $serverXMLPath

mkdir $tomcatLogsAccess
chown -R $tomcatSvcUsr $tomcatLogsAccess
chgrp -R $tomcatSvcGrp $tomcatLogsAccess

# modify server.xml add maxPostSize tags to http and ajp connectors
xmlstarlet ed -L -a '/Server/Service/Connector[@name="b"]' -t 'elem' -n 'maxPostSize' -v 0  -i '/Server/Service/Connector[not(@name)]' -t 'attr' -n 'maxPostSize' -v "$maxPostSize" $serverXMLPath

#edit tomcat801/bin/catalina.sh
#line 199 change catalina.out file location to
#CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/tomcat/catalina.out
sed -i -e "s~$catalinaShSearch~$catalinaShReplace~" $catalinaShPath

JAVA_HOME="$jdkDirPath"
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

#Add native library for PROD env. to speed up tomcat startup
yum -y install apr-devel openssl-devel 
cd $tomcatBinPath
tar -xvzf tomcat-native.tar.gz  
cd tomcat-native-1.1.33-src/jni/native  

yum -y install gcc

./configure --with-apr=/usr && make && sudo make install  
cd /usr/lib  
rm -f libtcnative-1.so  
ln -s /usr/local/apr/lib/libtcnative-1.so libtcnative-1.so 
chown -h $tomcatSvcUsr libtcnative-1.so
chgrp -h $tomcatSvcGrp libtcnative-1.so

cd $tomcatBinPath
rm -rf tomcat-native-1.1.33-src/

#yum -y remove gcc
#yum -y remove apr-devel
#yum -y remove openssl-devel
#yum -y remove epel-release
#yum -y remove xmlstarlet

service $tomcatSvcName start
service $tomcatSvcName status
```

**tomcat801_init.d.txt**

```html
#!/bin/bash
#
# tomcat801
#
# chkconfig: - 234 80 20
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: tomcat801
# Required-Start: $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $network $syslog
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Description: Tomcat 801
# Short-Description: start and stop tomcat
### END INIT INFO

## Source function library.
#. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/app/java/jdk1.8.0_45
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/app/tomcat801
TOMCAT_USER=tomcatUsr
TOMCAT_SVC=tomcatSvc
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=20

tomcat_pid() {
 echo `ps aux | ps -ef | grep $TOMCAT_SVC | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } '`
}

start() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ] 
  then
    echo "Tomcat is already running (pid: $pid)"
  else
    # Start tomcat
    echo "Starting tomcat"
    ulimit -n 100000
    umask 007
    /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh $TOMCAT_USER $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
  fi
  return 0
}

stop() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo "Stoping Tomcat"
    /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh $TOMCAT_USER $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh

    let kwait=$SHUTDOWN_WAIT
    count=0;
    until [ `ps -p $pid | grep -c $pid` = '0' ] || [ $count -gt $kwait ]
    do
      echo -n -e "\nwaiting for processes to exit";
   sleep 1
      let count=$count+1;
   echo ""
    done

    if [ $count -gt $kwait ]; then
      echo -n -e "\nkilling processes which didn't stop after $SHUTDOWN_WAIT seconds"
      kill -9 $pid
    fi
  else
    echo "Tomcat is not running"
  fi
 
  return 0
}

case $1 in
start)
  start
;; 
stop)   
  stop
;; 
restart)
  stop
  start
;;
status)
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo "Tomcat is running with pid: $pid"
  else
    echo "Tomcat is not running"
  fi
;; 
esac    
exit 0
```

**setenv.sh**

```html
#! /bin/bash

export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms1024m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:NewSize=512m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxNewSize=512m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:GCTimeRatio=9"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/appenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/appenv.sh"
fi

echo "Using CATALINA_OPTS:"
for arg in $CATALINA_OPTS
do
    echo ">> " $arg
done
echo ""

echo "Using JAVA_OPTS:"
for arg in $JAVA_OPTS
do
    echo ">> " $arg
done
echo "_______________________________________________"
echo ""
```

**faulty tomcat ps aux result**

```
root      50855  48981  0 07:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tomcatSvc
```

**working tomcat ps aux result**

```
  502        687     1  3 May31 ?        1-17:06:35 /opt/pilot/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/pilot/tomcatSvc/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms6000m -Xmx6000m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1500 -XX:GCTimeRatio=9 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/pilot/tomcatSvc/endorsed -classpath /opt/pilot/tomcatSvc/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/pilot/tomcatSvc/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/pilot/tomcatSvc-Dcatalina.home=/opt/pilot/tomcatSvc-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/pilot/tomcatSvc/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
    app     23441 23408  0 09:16 pts/0    00:00:00 grep tomcatSvc
```

Comment: _"...if they are different then something goes wrong ..."_ -- This is insufficient. What error messages appear in your console and logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understand your code is this command:

```
tomcat_pid() {
    echo `ps aux | ps -ef | grep $TOMCAT_SVC | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } '`
}
```

It should/could be:

```
tomcat_pid() {
    echo `ps aux | ps -ef | grep $tomcatDirName | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } '`
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `ps` command lists all running processes (including their paths), while `grep` filter that list based on your "keyword" (in your current code, it's $TOMCAT_SVC/tomcatSvc).

Looking at your "working tomcat ps aux result", I can see that **the application is started in folder tomcat802**. Furthermore, there is nothing called "tomcatSvc" inside the path:

> 502        687     1  3 May31 ?        1-17:06:35
>   /opt/pilot/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/pilot/tomcat802/conf/logging.properties
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli...

Therefore, if you keep the original command, the system will NOT find the correct PID (simply because there's no literal "tomcatsvc" in your executable path)
If you change to my recommended command, the system will find it.

**Warning**: this way of finding PID is kind of dangerous, since if you have another running program with path containing "tomcat802", that program could be selected instead. You want to put the absolute path instead of tomcat802; and make sure no one move that folder, or else the code might break.

Comment: i forgot to mention that in the working ps aux result  the tomcat service = tomcat802 not tomcatsvc, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Vagho:
so what is the issue? Your code works as it is supposed to be.

Comment: I think you get a little bit confused here with [$TOMCAT_SVC/tomcatSvcName]. It is only the service name. When you want to do ps | grep to find the process, you want to specify some keyword inside the path to your program. Therefore putting "echo `ps aux | ps -ef | grep $tomcatDirName..." seems to be the more correct choice here.

Comment: great mate ... thanks a lot , that was my issue .. could you please explain why it worked ? what was the issue in words since i am a newbie in linux

Comment: Check my edited answer. The code ps|grep basically say that: "I will get any PID with the word "...." in my path. You just need to put the right word.